# Retrieve the most recent from the parse database by sorting

Tags: java, parse-platform

I am new to Parse. I have a Class in parse which has the following fields :objectId entryTime exitTime. So I have many records with the same objectID and a different entryTime and exitTime. I want to be able to retrieve the most recent record from this class with the ObjectId and the most recent entryTimeStamp. How can I acheive this ?
So example of the records in my Class are as follows

```
 ObjectId            entryTime                          exitTime
1. O4ZnG0cr6C   Sat Feb 21 17:28:43 EST 2015  Sat Feb 21 17:28:43 EST 2015
2. O4ZnG0cr6C   Sat Feb 21 17:28:40 EST 2015  Sat Feb 21 17:29:43 EST 2015
```

If the current time is Sat Feb 21 17:28:44 EST 2015 I want to retrieve the top most record from this list.
Thank you.

Comment: What language are you coding in?

Comment: Java Programming Language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ascending()` or `descending()`.

For example if your query is called `query`, `query.ascending("parameter you want to sort")` should sort the results for you.

If that doesn't work you can try `query.orderByAscending("...")`

Note that the methods only take in strings/string variables.